# How to get HttpContext from a Nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware, httpcontext

I have create a class library in .net core 6 that includes middleware for http context. Then I get the request body like (where context is the HttpContext):

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var requestReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
        var requestContent = await requestReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        LogContext("HTTP Request", requestContent);
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        await _next(context);   }
```

This works fine if I keep it as a class library. However, if I build a nuget package and then install it into another api application, I get a "Not Supported" error. Is there a way to allow this to work without error?

Comment: are you sure your body is still readable at the point your middleware is invoked?

Comment: Well it works if I use it as a class library and I am able to get the body. Stops working when I deploy it as a nuget package and then add that package to another api.

Comment: Well figured out I missed the enabling of buffering in my new project. So that answers it.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thats why i asked ^^ glad you could solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call the EnableBuffering().